# Understanding Avogrado's hypothesis

Tags: gas-laws, pressure

I have read that gases under identical conditions of temperature, pressure, and volume contain the same number of molecules, but every gas has different types of atoms so their force of attraction is also different then how can this be true?

Comment: LOL - Avacado's number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant

Comment: The assumption of ideal gas says that the attractions are zero. To first approximation at low pressure, this is mostly true.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider **Ideal gas equation **
and ignore the type of interaction which are present in the real gases then ; 
$PV=nRT $
wherevP= pressure ; v=vol. ; n= moles; R = universal gas constant ; T= temp.

$PV/RT=constant $
so $n=constant$

so if$ n$ is constant then if we multiply it with avogadro's constant $N_A $ it would give you number of molecules .
Again that's when ideal gas .

Answer (score 0):

You are right to question Avogadro's hypothesis and your intuition is correct that it would not be true for gases with different attractive and repulsive forces. However, Avogadro's hypothesis defines an ideal gas: a gas where the particles themselves have no volume (no repulsive force) and the particles have no attractive forces. A gas that meets these conditions would perfectly follow Avogadro's hypothesis. While no gas is truly ideal, many behave almost ideally under the right conditions, such as very low pressures or high temperatures.